# My logo disappear after adding custom css, how to fix?

Tags: css, wordpress

I was trying to move my logo further left therefore added some css code to custom css field and found the logo is completely disappeared. I installed firebug and inspect the logo and header and found the logo is there but somewhere the code is overwritten. I can not fix it.
My original Logo css code was:

- GLOBAL */

body{background:url(images/body_bg.png);font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#555;line-height: 1.5; font-size:12px;}
.clearfix:after {content: ".";display: block;height: 0;clear: both;visibility: hidden;}

```
#header{max-width:920px;margin:20px auto;clear:both;display:block;vertical-align: top; position:relative; height:75px;}
#header_logo{background:url(images/header_logo.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;display:block;float:left;text-indent:-3000px; width:100%; height:75px; position:absolute;}

#breadcrum{font-size:11px;padding:4px 0 8px 0px;margin:0 auto;margin-bottom:10px;border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;width:920px;}
```

I added  the following code to custom css field:

```
#header_logo{background:url(images/header_logo.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;display:block;float:left;text-indent:-3000px; width:100%; height:75px; position:absolute;}
```

The code I found responsible via Firebug is:

```
#header_logo {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-image: url("images/header_logo.png");
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto auto;
  display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: -3000px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

WHen i disable background-image: url("images/header_logo.png");  and the height:75;
the whole logo reappear. but its in firebug, i don't know how to do this on my actual theme. I can not find the how and where to fix it.Any help is greatly appreciated. site is auromarealty.com

Answer (score 0):

It's because you added...

```
#header_logo{background:url(images/header_logo.png) ...
```

When I try to access that file...which is: http://auromarealty.com/images/header_logo.png Nothing exists. So either upload the `header_logo.png` file into your `/images/` dir or change that entire CSS line to...

```
#header_logo{background:url(http://auromarealty.com/wp-content/uploads/thefirm/thefirm_header_logo.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;display:block;float:left;text-indent:-3000px; width:100%; height:75px; position:absolute;}
```

That should fix it! Mark as answer if it did...thanks :)

Comment: Sorry but it did not work, still the same problem and i checked via firebug---still its showing up when i disable background-image: url("images/header_logo.png");   and height:75;                                                                 I think somewhere the code is overwritten but dont'knwow here to fix it. Have any idea/ If you see via firebug or inspect the logo part you can see it clearly. Thanks for your reply though but I still need help urgently:)

Comment: View the raw source code for the entire homepage of auromarealty.com. On line 31 of that generated source you'll see where it's being overwritten. Therefore, what you're seeing is that when you disable the style with the broken image path (as I pointed out previously) line 31 with the embedded CSS kicks in and it works because the image path is correct (as I pointed out above). If you remove the background property completely from YOUR #header_logo definition then it'll work. Your image file path is broke.

Comment: @gbdevHi
How to do that? Remove "If you remove the background property completely from YOUR #header_logo definition"
I removed the "#header_logo{background:url(http://auromarealty.com/wp-content/uploads/thefirm/thefirm_header_logo.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;display:block;float:left;text-indent:-3000px;height:75px; width:100%; position:absolute;}" completely from my CSS but its the same. Could you ple tell me from which file I have to delete and is I am not an expert, cant do this. Sorry but can u just tell me which is the actual file I have to delete?
Thanks

Comment: I think I have to do the site again from the scratch?

Comment: No you do not have to do the site again from scratch. Just remove  your #header_logo CSS declaration you added (like you did in Firebug) and the other declaration will pick up because of [CSS specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).